# Since Compose BOM 2023.08.00, instrumented tests are failing, because lazy list changes seem to be leaving old nodes in the hierarchy

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, android-espresso, android-jetpack

Jetpack Compose version: Compose BOM 2023.08.00

Jetpack Compose component(s) used: Foundation, material, animations, livedata, ui-tooling, viewmodel

Kotlin version: 1.9.10

Steps to Reproduce or Code Sample to Reproduce:

- When adding an item to a lazyColumn, and pushing a bottom item lower in the column, the item node is duplicated. This is making my instrumented tests fail because there are multiple nodes with the same test tag. This did not happen pre-compose BOM 2023.08.00
- Please view the attached screenshots. Nodes remain persistent in the hierarchy when the lazy list items change. If you look at both screenshots, one of them shows the real node where the button is present, and we can see parameters on the node. The other screenshot shows a phantom node, where the button used to be. It does not have parameters.

**Has anyone experienced this and if so are there workarounds to target visible nodes only in compose instrumented tests, without getting ambiguous node exceptions?**

Here is some sample code of my lazyColumn implementation:

```
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.testTag(COMMUTE_ITEM_LIST),
        state = state
    ) {
        item { Spacer(modifier= Modifier.height(topPaddingDp)) }
        items(itemViews.size, key = { itemViews[it].uniqueId }) { index ->
            AnimateItemPlacements {
                CommuteItemRow(
                    modifier = Modifier,
                    itemViews = itemViews,
                    index = index,
                    onRemoveItemAtIndex = onRemoveItemAtIndex,
                    onEditItemAtIndex = onEditItemAtIndex,
                    onItemMoved = onItemMoved
                )
            }
        }

        item {
            AddItemButton(
                modifier = Modifier,
                index = itemViews.size,
                onAddItemAtIndex = onAddItemAtIndex
            )
        }
        item {
            Spacer(Modifier.height(bottomPaddingDp))
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Link to issue tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/299304333

Comment: Have you seen [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187188981)? It seems to describe your problem, correct?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Yes, this seems like the exact issue. The workaround in post #12 seems to offer an unclean but good enough solution for now!

Answer (score 3):

After looking through https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187188981, there is a workaround that ended up working for me.

The issue is that some nodes remain cached in lazy lists and tests now throw exceptions when trying to single out a specific node with calls like this:

```
composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("testTag")
```

The workaround solution in the meantime (until the Compose team fixes this issue) is to use these extension functions, courtesy of the poster in post #12 of the above link:

```
/** A patched version of [ComposeTestRule.onNode] that filters out cached views from lazy views. */
fun ComposeTestRule.onNodePatched(matcher: SemanticsMatcher) =
    onNode(matcher and isNotCached())

/** A patched version of [ComposeTestRule.onNodeWithText] that filters out cached views from lazy views. */
fun ComposeTestRule.onNodeWithTextPatched(text: String, substring: Boolean = false, ignoreCase: Boolean = false, useUnmergedTree: Boolean = false) =
    onAllNodesWithText(text = text, substring = substring, ignoreCase = ignoreCase, useUnmergedTree = useUnmergedTree)
        .filterToOneNotCached()

/** A patched version of [ComposeTestRule.onNodeWithTag] that filters out cached views from lazy views. */
fun ComposeTestRule.onNodeWithTagPatched(testTag: String, useUnmergedTree: Boolean = false) =
    onAllNodesWithTag(testTag = testTag, useUnmergedTree = useUnmergedTree)
        .filterToOneNotCached()

/** A patched version of [ComposeTestRule.onNodeWithContentDescription] that filters out cached views from lazy views. */
fun ComposeTestRule.onNodeWithContentDescriptionPatched(label: String) =
    onAllNodesWithContentDescription(label = label)
        .filterToOneNotCached()

/** A patched version of [ComposeTestRule.onAllNodesWithText] that filters out cached views from lazy views. */
fun ComposeTestRule.onAllNodesWithTextPatched(text: String) =
    onAllNodesWithText(text = text)
        .filterOutCached()

/** A patched version of [ComposeTestRule.onAllNodesWithContentDescription] that filters out cached views from lazy views. */
fun ComposeTestRule.onAllNodesWithContentDescriptionPatched(label: String) =
    onAllNodesWithContentDescription(label = label)
        .filterOutCached()

/** Filters out cached views from lazy views and expects 1 or 0 results. */
fun SemanticsNodeInteractionCollection.filterToOneNotCached() =
    filterToOne(isNotCached())

/** Filters out cached views from lazy views and expects 0 or more results. */
fun SemanticsNodeInteractionCollection.filterOutCached() =
    filter(isNotCached())

/**
 * Matches against only nodes that are not "cached" by lazy lists. This allows us to filter out
 * nodes that do not appear in the UI but are reported by Compose's testing framework. These cached
 * nodes cause issues because they will cause assertIsDisplayed to fail due to 2 nodes with the same
 * values are reportedly displayed, but one is displayed and the other is cached. Cached nodes also
 * cause assertDoesNotExist to fail because the cached node that does not exist on the UI does exist
 * according to the test framework.
 *
 * This matcher is used in the methods above to globally filter out these very unexpected nodes.
 * We hope Compose stops reporting these cached nodes in a future update and we can remove this patch.
 *
 * https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187188981
 */
fun isNotCached() = SemanticsMatcher("isNotCached") { node -> node.layoutInfo.isPlaced }
```